# Problem in a code for CS50 CREDIT assignment

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write code for Credit Problem set in CS50 (Credit), i'm at the very beginning but here's a problem I came across. Right now I'm trying to extract card digits to operate with them later and checking if the extraction went well. Code seems to work for every digit in a card number except for the 12th (starting from the end).

e.g.
Card number:
input: 1111111111111111
output:1111111111101111

Though in some cases this problem doesn't occur:

input:
1234567890123456
output:
1234567890123456

Here's my code (please don't be too harsh, I'm a newbie:))
I'm aware that there are other ways to get those digits, but I just really want to now why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

long card_no(void);
int main(void)
{
    long card = card_no();
    int one = (card % 10);
    int two = (card % 100 - card % 10) * 0.1;
    int tree = (card % 1000 - card % 100) * 0.01;
    int four = (card % 10000 - card % 1000) * 0.001;
    int five = (card % 100000 - card % 10000) * 0.0001;
    int six = (card % 1000000 - card % 100000) * 0.00001;
    int seven = (card % 10000000 - card % 1000000) * 0.000001;
    int eight = (card % 100000000 - card % 10000000) * 0.0000001;
    int nine = (card % 1000000000 - card % 100000000) * 0.00000001;
    int ten = (card % 10000000000 - card % 1000000000) * 0.000000001;
    int eleven = (card % 100000000000 - card % 10000000000) * 0.0000000001;
    int twelve = (card % 1000000000000 - card % 100000000000) * 0.00000000001;
    int thirteen = (card % 10000000000000 - card % 1000000000000) * 0.000000000001;
    int forteen = (card % 100000000000000 - card % 10000000000000) * 0.0000000000001;
    int fifteen = (card % 1000000000000000 - card % 100000000000000) * 0.00000000000001;
    int sixteen = (card % 10000000000000000 - card % 1000000000000000) * 0.000000000000001;

    printf("%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i\n", sixteen, fifteen, forteen, thirteen, twelve, eleven, ten, nine, eight, seven, six, five, four, tree, two, one);

}

//Prompt user for 13 to 16 digits card number
long card_no(void)
{
    long n;
    do
    {
       n = get_long("Card number:\n"); 
    }
    while (n < 1000000000000 || n > 9999999999999999);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the card number won't fit in a long. Why not process as a string, getting each digit separately?

Comment: Or there can be imprecision when you multiply with a floating point number. Why not use integer division, `/`?

Comment: What exactly is the program supposed to do? Anyway it looks totally weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point math isn't exact - values like `0.1` cannot be represented *exactly* in a finite number of bits, so you only get an approximation like `0.099...` or `0.1000...1` or something like that.  So after doing the math for your fifth digit you wind up with a value of `0.9...`, which gives `0` when converted to an `int`.

Another option that doesn't rely on floating point math is to divide the number by increasing magnitude and taking the `% 10` of the result.  IOW,

```
(123 /   1) % 10  == 123 % 10 == 3
(123 /  10) % 10  ==  12 % 10 == 2
(123 / 100) % 10  ==   1 % 10 == 1
```

Integer division yields an integer result - any fractional portion is discarded.

Handy hint, when you find yourself creating a bunch of variables of the same type with ordinal names (`first`, `second`, `third` or `one`, `two`, `three`) that's a really strong hint that you want to use an *array*:

```
#define  NUM_DIGITS 16
int digits[NUM_DIGITS];

/** 
 * get card number as before
 */

long magnitude = 1;
/**
 * Arrays are indexed from 0 to N-1
 */
for ( size_t i = 0; i < NUM_DIGITS; i++ ) 
  digits[i] = (card / magnitude) % 10;
  magnitude *= 10;
}

/**
 * I typically use size_t for array indices, which is an unsigned type.
 * This means it cannot represent negative values.  If we loop while "i >= 0",
 * then the loop will never exit, since subtracting 1 from 0 will "wrap
 * around" to the largest value.  So even though the array is indexed from
 * NUM_DIGITS-1 to 0, we loop over NUM_DIGITS to 1 and subtract 1 from 
 * i in the subscript operation.
 */
for ( size_t i = NUM_DIGITS; i > 0; i-- ) 
  printf( "%d", digits[i-1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This little bit of code might show you a MUCH easier way to get going.
It extracts all the digits of a number, one at a time, without using increasingly gigantic numbers like `10000000`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long card_number = 564879165464;
    int counter = 1;

    while(card_number)
    {
        printf("Digit %d = %d\n", counter++, card_number % 10);
        card_number /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Digit 1 = 4
Digit 2 = 6
Digit 3 = 4
Digit 4 = 5
Digit 5 = 6
Digit 6 = 1
Digit 7 = 9
Digit 8 = 7
Digit 9 = 8
Digit 10 = 4
Digit 11 = 6
Digit 12 = 5
```